# Save a variable from an User Task and use as condition variable

Tags: java, database, alfresco, activiti, bpmn

At my user task I am filling some data(which won't be stored in ACT_RU_VARIABLE) and as soon as I click the submit button, i am invoking taskService.complete(). Now lets say if I want to use, one field which I fill at the user task, as a condition variable. How do i do that assuming we are using only activiti's 28 tables?

example: Lets say we have a leaveRequest, the leave is approved if its less than 3 days and rejected otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Just save value of you task variable to the execution and so you can use it to decide about next step.

```
execution.setVariable("your_variable_name", "variable_value") = task.getVariable("your_variable_name");
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: i think you misunderstood, or my question was not clear.
i'm actually filling a form and storing the data in some other database, on clicking submit, the user task completes, i.e taskService.complete().

Comment: That being the case, you will need to add a task listener on completion of the task to pull the value from your eternal DB and set the variable in the context as Lu suggests.